# How to prevent the output truncated if the rows of output from the windbg to large？

Tags: windbg

If  the output rows from the windbg command to large ，such as 100k rows, finally the windbg just display thousands of the rows, and most of them would be truncated , so my question is how to prevent the output truncated , or write all of the rows from the output to a local file to keep all of the output rows? the "write Windows text to file" wouldn't helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sometimes simply piping works especially when running cdb and quitting after executing just one command

```
cdb -c "tc 100;q" calc >> foo.txt
```

you should have 100 calls lets check

```
grep  -c !.*: foo.txt
256
```

lets check how many sysenter were done and what were the index of the syscalls

```
grep  sysenter  -B 4 foo.txt | grep eax | awk "{print $1}"
eax=000000ea
eax=0000014d
eax=000000fb
```

we can use the output when the commands run for an  infinite amount of time
without having file locked issues

like this

[image]

if .logopen .logclose isnt an option

Comment: Nice but what "file locked issues" are you talking about?

Comment: @MarcSherman  well it may be wrong terminology but try running the same commands from windbg instead of cdb using .logopen and experience the responsiveness between them to understand  the issue

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it would help, but [`.logopen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564018(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`.logclose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563991(v=vs.85).aspx) commands might be helpful in this case (respectively open and close a log file which keeps a copy of the events and commands from the Debugger Command window).

See also [`Keeping a Log File in WinDbg`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh451024(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try to open additional command window with Ctrl+N and execute the long outputed command within it